# How to test the default NLTK NER chunker's accuracy on own corpus?

Tags: python, nltk

How to test the default NLTK NER chunker's accuracy on own corpus?

I've tagged a percentage of my own corpus. I'm curious if it's possible to use the default NLTK tagger to see accuracy rate on this corpus?

I already know about the ne_chunker.evaluate() function, but it's not immediately clear to me how to input in my own corpus for evaluation (rather than the gold standard corpus)

Answer (score 0):

Read in the chunked portion of your corpus and convert it into the format that the NLTK expects, i.e. as a list of shallow `Tree`s. Once you have it in this form, you can pass it to the `evaluate()` method just like you would pass the "gold standard" examples.

The `evaluate` method will strip off the chunks, run your text through the chunker, and compare the result with the chunks you supplied to calculate accuracy.